# Will oyster mushrooms eat my cupboard?

Tags: mushrooms

I'm incubating oyster mycelium in a cupboard. When the fruiting bodies come, and they sporulate, will that endanger the cupboard itself ?

Comment: Hi Jimmy Widdle! I'm not sure this question is on-topic because it's not strictly about gardening. Even though growing mushrooms is on-topic, I don't think that what happens to them inside a cabinet fits into the site definition according to the [What topics can I ask about?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page in our [help]. It's an interesting question, but I think it's beyond the scope of what we do. I'm just one person, though, and can easily be wrong!

Comment: - garden or landscape planning and layout;
(should I grow in  a cupboard?)
- the practice of gardening, including timing, tools and techniques.
(should I use the grow-in-a-cupboard technique?)

Comment: Jimmy - it sounds like this may be your first time growing oyster mushrooms. If that is the case, then please don't underestimate the ability of these species to release huge spore loads nor how harmful those spores can be if inhaled. Please refer to this for more information on the dangers: https://www.reddit.com/r/mycology/comments/1eqibm/is_an_indoor_oyster_mushroom_farm_dangerous/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way fungus will harm your cabinets or any wood is if that wood is already in a condition that is conducive for being decomposed; it has to be constantly moist, little air, no sunlight.  Then fungus will be able to use your cabinets for energy.  Mushrooms are the reproductive part of some fungus organisms. Not all.

So not to worry.

Your question is most certainly is within this site's parameters. My opinion of course.  We need to know how to live with fungus just as we need to be able to grow green plants. Where else would you find information on fungus?  Great question but this site is careful about the types of questions.  Shoot, Gardening and Landscaping cover just about everything!  Grins.

Comment: Just two comments - sunlight is typically not detrimental to mycelial growth beyond the tendency of sunlight to dry a substrate out. And when it comes to fruiting, sunlight (not direct) is essential for good production of mushrooms themselves. Second - Fungi are a kingdom unto themselves, and not part of the Plant Kingdom.

Comment: Ah yes, I can put them somewhere else then.

Comment: Well, now I've succeeded in getting some fruiting bodies, and seen spores dusted all around them, I'm a bit worried for my floorboards and other wood in the house. I've got some blocks on shelves in my bedroom where the boards are bare, in the bathroom where it's moist. I'm nervous about spores getting into the structure of the house. I was thinking surely there must be stories of this happening if it does, or even warnings ?

Answer (score 2):

Although oyster mushrooms like birch , which your cabinets may be , I am highly doubtful that you will get mushrooms , and I promise they won't eat you cabinets. When I have found them it has been , or following cold,
 wet weather ,eg 50 F ; seems unlikely for a cabinet.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use your kitchen cupboards as a fruiting chamber. Once the bags are fully colonized, and they start to fruit you'll need to provide oxygen and light otherwise they won't grow well. Since the bulk of the mushroom is water you'll need to keep misting them which could damage the wood, but without the increased oxygen and light they won't do well.

If the wood is kept moist from misting you might get surface molds developing which you can wipe off.